# Need help to improve a T-SQL query

Tags: database, sql-server-2008

I have a table that contains about 32 million rows. In this table there is `item_id` (not primary key) and text column.

What I want to do is to concatenate text columns with same `item_id`'s. And use this in a report.

So far we've been using `FOR XML PATH` keyword to concatenate. But our customer are not happy with the latency.

So we tried COALESCE (we tried the method described [here](http://www.ialpine.net/post/MS-SQL-Merge-values-from-multiple-rows-into-one-row.aspx)) we didn't get a proper result (or maybe it was going to take too long)

So guys, if you know better method, technique can you help me about this issue?

Thanks...

Comment: You should post both queries you're trying.. (`FOR XML PATH` one and `COALESCE` one)

Comment: Is the item_id column indexed?

Comment: String concatenatation is slow. So is searching strings and parsing strings. That's just the way it is. I would push to reformat the report or select fewer rows or a caching strategy.

Comment: Also forget that this table generated and filled by an ERP software, so I don't have control too much. @MikeChristensen you can look at the link I gave, its pretty much the same

Comment: I wonder about the naive approach: doing it in code: order by item_id, timest; doing a level break on item_id. That would be the most streamlined as you would not need to actually concatenate the texts. Though there is more database - application communication. (I assume appropiate indices, only used columns selected.)

Comment: Read up on indexed Views:  Sounds like you could benefit from them in this instance. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd171921(v=sql.100).aspx  The job that generates the table and fills it could kick off a job which materializes the updates thus the heavy lifting is done before a user runs the report. Or it could be timed to begin after that job is known to complete etc...  combined with for XML path I think you'll get the results your looking for.

Comment: Also, since there's 32 million rows, would a clustered index on `item_id` help for read access?

Comment: @xQbert thanks I will look at it. I'm sorry unfortunately remote sql server crashed or something, I can't reach now. Once I reach I will answer if it is indexed or not.

Comment: There are more than one way to for xml path to concatenate strings. Please post the way you do it. Tip, the version that uses select distinct is really slow. Doing a group by is alot faster.

Answer (score 0):

Add an index for the **item_id** column.

Answer (score 0):

- Maybe use compressed data as field instead of characters.
- Use a table with item_id as primary key with as fields: last text id, and concatenated text from first id to last id. Update this table incremental. Should be faster. Costs double space.

Answer (score 0):

Do all of these:

1. Create indexes for the fields which are part of your where.
2. Instead of using Descartes multiplication use joins (if you are using Descartes multiplication in your query).
3. In your where clause put the quicker and less probable logical operands first. For instance where A and B is true if both of them are true, so if A is false, B won't be calculated at all and you win a lot of time. This might be a difference of doing hundreds of thousands of logical checking or not doing it, so, of course this is an optimization.

I hope this helps.